# Spring integration: http inbound gateway log original HTTP request

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

How can I see the original HTTP incoming request when using http inbound gateway?

I want to see the original HTTP headers before the mapping performed by `mappedRequestHeaders(String pattern...)`.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing the logger level of spring web?

Comment: I didn't know it was the same logger than Spring Web. I used this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging and worked, thanks!

Comment: Yes. Spring Integration HTTP module is fully based on Spring MVC and whatever you can configure on the server side will be applied for those Integration endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

As @Horsing and @Artem Billan pointed in the comments, Spring Integration HTTP module is fully based on Spring MVC so [these](https://baeldung.com/spring-http-logging) kind of solutions will work.